# How to search within ListView with custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I looked at the following site: [**ListView Example**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Which describes how to implement a search function in a listview which uses the default adapter and it works fine.

How can I modify it so I can use the same for a Custom Adapter for my listview?

Partial code is:

```
        dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFiles);
        tvQuote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        tvQuote.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(MainActivity.this.getAssets(), "fonts/roboto.ttf"));

        for (int y=0; y<strNamesOfAllah.length;y++) {
            name = strNamesOfAllah[y];
            meaning = strMeaning[y];
            rowsArray.add(new SetRows(R.drawable.icon, name, meaning));
        }
        adapter = new SetRowsCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.customlist, rowsArray);
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dataList.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override getFilter inside of your adapter and return a new customFilter object that you create. See this answer: [No results with custom ArrayAdapter Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255322/no-results-with-custom-arrayadapter-filter/8258457#8258457)

Edit:

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(customFilter == null){
            customFilter = new CustomFilter();
        }
        return customFilter;
    }
```

Comment: I found a good example here: http://www.9android.net/add-search-function-to-custom-listview/ but i am not sure how to modify the getFilter() to work with my base adapter (http://pastebin.com/zSsv7862)

Comment: Simply override getFilter and create a new one if one does not exist already, see my edit above

Comment: Is that the full code? I found a custom filter function but some of the variable I am confused about. Can you take a look?

Comment: That getFilter code should go in your adapter and you should create your own CustomFilter class similar to the one in the link I posted above.

Comment: This helped me complete the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function