# SearchView doesn't work when searching rows in a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, search

I have a project where I can add data,delete them and update them using SQLite. Of course I display them in a listview. The last thing I want to do is a use a searchView object,so the user can search the data he wants and check if they are there. However the SearchView object does nothing. I type on purpose something that exists in the listview and the matched row doesn't appear.

[image: my project's image]

Here is my code.

```
public class DisplayForldersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHandler dba;

private ArrayList<MyFolder> dbFolders = new ArrayList<>();
private FolderAdapter folderAdapter;
private ListView listView;

SearchView inputSearch;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_forlders);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    inputSearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


    fetchDataFromDB();


}

private void fetchDataFromDB() {
    dbFolders.clear();
    dba = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    ArrayList<MyFolder> foldersFromDB = dba.getFolderDetails();

    for(int i=0; i<foldersFromDB.size();i++){

        String plateNo = foldersFromDB.get(i).getPlateNumber();
        String owner = foldersFromDB.get(i).getOwnerName();
        String cardId = foldersFromDB.get(i).getCardId();
        String content = foldersFromDB.get(i).getContent();
        String date = foldersFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
        int mid = foldersFromDB.get(i).getItemId();

        MyFolder f = new MyFolder();
        f.setPlateNumber(plateNo);
        f.setOwnerName(owner);
        f.setCardId(cardId);
        f.setContent(content);
        f.setRecordDate(date);
        f.setItemId(mid);

        dbFolders.add(f);

        folderAdapter = new FolderAdapter(DisplayForldersActivity.this,R.layout.folders_row,dbFolders);
        listView.setAdapter(folderAdapter);
        folderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        inputSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                folderAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    dba.close();
}
```

And my adapter's code

```
 private class FolderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyFolder>{
    Activity activity;
    int layoutResource;
    MyFolder myFolder;
    ArrayList<MyFolder> mData = new ArrayList<>();


    public FolderAdapter(Activity act, int resource, ArrayList<MyFolder> data) {
        super(act, resource,data);

        activity = act;
        layoutResource = resource;
        mData = data;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyFolder getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null || row.getTag()==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource,null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.mPlateNo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.plateNumberList);
            //holder.mOwner = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ownerName);
            holder.mcardId = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.idNumber);
            //holder.mContent = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.processing);
            holder.mDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dateText);

            row.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        holder.myF = getItem(position);

        holder.mPlateNo.setText(holder.myF.getPlateNumber());
        //holder.mOwner.setText(holder.myF.getOwnerName());
        //holder.mcardId.setText(holder.myF.getCardId());
        //holder.mPlateNo.setText(holder.myF.getPlateNumber());
        holder.mDate.setText(holder.myF.getRecordDate());
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;


        holder.mPlateNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String dateText = finalHolder.myF.getRecordDate().toString();
                String owner = finalHolder.myF.getOwnerName().toString();
                String cardId = finalHolder.myF.getCardId().toString();
                String plateNumber = finalHolder.myF.getCardId().toString();
                String content = finalHolder.myF.getContent().toString();

                int mid = finalHolder.myF.getItemId();


                Intent i = new Intent(DisplayForldersActivity.this,DetailedFolderActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id",mid);
                i.putExtra("owner",owner);
                i.putExtra("cardId",cardId);
                i.putExtra("plateNumber",plateNumber);
                i.putExtra("content",content);
                i.putExtra("dateText",dateText);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        MyFolder myF;
        int mid;
        TextView mPlateNo;
        TextView mOwner;
        TextView mcardId;
        TextView mContent;
        TextView mDate;


    }


}
```

Did I do something wrong? Thanks

Comment: no, no ,no, if your data come from an sqlite db use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Try calling notifyDataSetChange on your adapter in mainActivity after this line " folderAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);"

Comment: If you have more than one `TextView` in your `ListView` row, `SearchView` wont search if you implement everything for that.

Comment: I need an exact solution basically. But I think the SearchView is trivial. I mean I could post those data in a server,and do the search thing with an appropriate webservice.

Comment: @Theo so this is how it works: http://pastebin.com/e7HLF6X6

Comment: Yeap. Thanks for the link and help.

Comment: But I haven't tried this code to my project yet. I will come to later

Answer (score 0):

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged in the adapter attached to the listView to invalidate the ListView and make it draw the changed/removed/inserted lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your array adapter needs to implement Filterable interface, which will override getFilter() method. Then in your getFilter() method you can perform your filtering opertion.

Check out this stackoverflow link, this code might help you out
[No results with custom ArrayAdapter Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255322/no-results-with-custom-arrayadapter-filter)

Answer (score 0):

The SerchView doesn't handle any search, it is just a widget. You have to implement the search logic by your own. Try the solution described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

You can also do this by calling SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener) and pass in a custom implementation of the listener.