# Search item from extended ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, search, android-arrayadapter

I'm using `ArrayAdapter` to show list item in `ListView` Every thing is working fine but Know I want to search item from this list. Actually these are the contact list which contains names and phone. I want only search according to names.

I write some code for search there is no error in it nor any run time error but search functionality is not working.

**MainActivity**

```
        EditText contactSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactSearch);
        contactSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                contentAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

**ContentAdapter**

```
 public class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Context context;
private String[] names;
private String[] phones;
public static Dialog dialog;

/*ContentAdapter(Context ctx, List<String> rows){
    super(ctx, R.layout.contact_row,R.id.txtName, rows);
    context = ctx;
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
}*/
ContentAdapter(Context ctx, String[] name, String[] phone){
    super(ctx, R.layout.contact_row,R.id.txtName,name);
    context = ctx;
    names = name;
    phones = phone;
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView name, phone;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNumber);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String phoneNumber = phone.getText().toString();
                String userName = name.getText().toString();
                //final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle(userName);
                EditText etxtContactNumber = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etxtContactNumber);
                etxtContactNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.name.setText(names[position]);
    viewHolder.phone.setText(phones[position]);

    return row;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Filter.FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                if (names[i].contains(constraint)) {
                    values.add(names[i]);
                }
                filterResults.values = values;
                filterResults.count = values.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}

}
```

At the end of the code you can see search function which I used to search. I'm new in android I don't know what I'm missing there.

Comment: use like [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/)

Comment: They are using BaseAdapter while I'm using ArrayAdapter

Comment: I think that you need to combine the string arrays into one single ArrayList. I've a blog on ListView with ArrayList filter sample: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/ Hope it help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search item from custom listView in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569882/search-item-from-custom-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText contactSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactSearch);
    contactSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           contentAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Try this

Comment: Would you like to try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8258457/6333971) ?